# How to identify if the controls has gone or not in flutter chewie video player

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-video-player

I am working on a flutter app and using chewie videoplayer plugin.So when we started playing a video it shows controls at bottom and after few seconds it vanishes and when we move  the mouse again it shows again. so is there any method to find when the controls are shown on screen and when its not shown.
actually i am giving close button on the video player. but it doesnt vanishes with those video player controls. it still stay on screen so to hide that close button along with video controls i need to get which process hides the control.
Please help me...[image: i need to know when these controls appears and hides]

Answer (score 0):

This process is inside the source code of chewie player. So if you need to customize and synchronise your own custom controls and options, either you have to explicitly fetch the source code and edit in that or you need to make your own controllers from scratch using video_player package as the core.

Comment: ok..so any other way to hide that cross icon when mouse is not moved

Comment: If you want to add this feature along with using chewie package, then you can use the chewie player and your custom control inside a stack and also you controller in a gesturewidget. Next you can control the visibility of you controller(cross) according to user or mouse interact with the screen.

Comment: is there any example for the solution. it will be more helpfull

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the source code of the chewie player.
You can find *MaterialControl class* inside the source code of this package there is a function called **_buildHitArea()** just change **notifier.hideStuff** boolean according to your preference.

```
Widget _buildHitArea() {
final bool isFinished = _latestValue.position >= _latestValue.duration;
final bool showPlayButton = widget.showPlayButton && !_dragging && !notifier.hideStuff;
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    if (_latestValue.isPlaying) {
      if (_displayTapped) {
        setState(() {
          notifier.hideStuff = false;
        });
      } else {
        _cancelAndRestartTimer();
      }
    } else {
      _playPause();

      setState(() {
        notifier.hideStuff = false;
      });
    }
  },
  child: CenterPlayButton(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
    iconColor: Colors.white,
    isFinished: isFinished,
    isPlaying: controller.value.isPlaying,
    show: showPlayButton,
    onPressed: _playPause,
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: con you please help on how to give this builthitarea in chewie. is there any full example for this.

Comment: It's already in the source code of the package. You just need to copy the MaterialControls code of the package and paste into your lib folder. After that you can edit it according to your preference.